# A question regarding properties of upper and Lower riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

This question was part of my analysis quiz and I couldn't solve it.

> Let $f:[1/2,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ , a strictly increasing function, put $g(x)=f(x)+f(1/x) $, $x \in [1,2]$. Consider a partition $P$ of $[1,2]$ and then which of following holds:

(a) for a suitable $f$ we can have $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$

(b) For a suitable $f$ we can have $U(P,g) \neq L(P,g)$.

(c) $U(P,g) \geq L(P,g)$ for all choices of $f$.

(d) $U(p,g )<L(P,g)$ for all choices of $f $.

I have question in only (a) and (b) ie how to prove / disprove then .I need help as I was unable to do them despite trying a lot.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: You are using $g$ for $f$?

Comment: @zhw. No , options C,D are written as it is in quiz.

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't read it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down.

Firstly, you agree that, by definition, c) is true and d) is false.

Secondly, let's examine in which cases would $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$, for a given partition $P$ of $[1,2]$. Both of these quantities are the integrals of step functions $\phi_U\geq\phi_L$ that are equal iff $g$ is a step function in $[1,2]$ that coincides with the partition $P$.

The simplest example for a $g$ that satisfies the above is $g=c$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, the question becomes can we find an $f$ st $f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})=c$ and there is a simple example of a usual function that does that.

Finally, about any $f$ you can think of confirms b).

Comment: for the last third line the function that satisfies it is $x^2 -c x+1=0 $ , am I right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the last third". Also, please accept the answer if you think it is sufficient so as not to keep the question "unanswered".

Comment: Consider last third line of your answer, does  the function that satisfies f(x)+f(1/x)=c is   x2−cx+1=0 ?

Comment: Firstly, $x^2-cx+1=0$ isn't a function, but a n equation, and the function $f(x)=x^2-cx+1$ doesn't satisfy $f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})=k$ (just take $x=1$ and $x=2$). I'm thinking about a usual function for which $f(x)=-f(\frac{1}{x})$.